# Return JSON String from AsyncTask Android

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

Normally I create classes for every web service call that extends with the **AsyncTask** and it's so hard to maintain the code. So I think to create the One class and get the OUTPUT Json string according to the parameters.
how do I return the JSON string?

**UPDATE**

Here what I tried

```
public class WebCallController extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>
 {
String PassPeram = "";
JSONStringer JSonRequestString;
String URL;
String JSonResponseString;

public WebCallController(String PerameterPass, JSONStringer JSonRequestString, String URL) {
    PassPeram = PerameterPass;
    this.JSonRequestString = JSonRequestString;
    this.URL = URL;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);
    post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    try {
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(JSonRequestString.toString());
        post.setEntity(entity);
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {

    }


    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        StatusLine status = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = status.getStatusCode();

        if(statusCode == 400)
        {
            Log.d("Error", "bad request");
        }
        else if(statusCode == 505)
        {
            Log.d("Error","Internal server error");
        }
        else
        {
            InputStream jsonStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(jsonStream));

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                builder.append(line);
            }

            JSonResponseString = builder.toString();

        }
    }
    catch (IOException Ex)
    {

    }
    return JSonResponseString;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show what you tried?

Comment: show your code on how you implement it..

Comment: Check out my answer, it might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        return "Executed";
    }

    @Override
    protected String onPostExecute(String result) {

        return "json String";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this may be what you are looking for(get string as result and parse it to json):

```
  YourAsycTask yat=new YourAsycTask();

yat.execute();

String result=yat.get().toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try out below code and put it in separate class from where it returns json string to your activity.

Only pass your url to this method and get the response in a string formate.

```
 public static final String GetConnectionInputStream(String strUrl) {
    String line = null;
    String response = null;
    try {

        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is
        // established.
        // The default value is zero, that means the timeout is not used.
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 30000);
        // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT)
        // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 30000);
        // This is the default apacheconnection.
        HttpClient mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

        // Pathe of serverside
        HttpGet mHttpGet = new HttpGet(strUrl);

        // get the valu from the saerverside as response.
        HttpResponse mHttpResponse = mHttpClient.execute(mHttpGet);
        HttpEntity mHttpEntity = mHttpResponse.getEntity();

        try {
            // convert response in to the string.
            if (mHttpEntity.getContent() != null) {
                BufferedReader mBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(mHttpEntity.getContent(),
                                HTTP.UTF_8), 8);
                StringBuilder mStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = mBufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    mStringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
                }
                response = mStringBuilder.toString();

                // mInputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return response;
}
```

Change your `doInBackground` method as below:

```
private class GetParsedResponse extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
     }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

         String response=null;
          response=GetConnectionInputStream(URL);

         return response;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        //your response parsing code.
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try this but I found the answer in previous answer. thanks for help.

Comment: In your question you have asked for the common method which reads json response from url and return in form of string. I did not get that only asynctask method answer had useful to you. That means you had asked wrong in your question.

Comment: I made a mistake when trying a code in doInBackground Method and I found It's from your answer.I changed the Void to String ,then it's not return the JSON string. then I saw the previous answer and copied it.It's working now. I need to return JSON string.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you need to write one `AsyncTask` which can be reusable for every webservice call. You can do something like below example ,

**Step-1: Create a `abstract class`**

```
public abstract class HttpHandler {

    public abstract HttpUriRequest getHttpRequestMethod();

    public abstract void onResponse(String result);

    public void execute(){
        new AsyncHttpTask(this).execute();
    } 
}
```

**2. Sterp-2: Write your `AsyncTask` code**

```
public class AsyncHttpTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    private HttpHandler httpHandler;
    public AsyncHttpTask(HttpHandler httpHandler){
        this.httpHandler = httpHandler;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
       //do your task and return the result
        String result = "";


        return result;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        httpHandler.onResponse(result); // set it to the onResponse()
    }


}
```

**Step-3: Write your `Activity` code**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button btnRequest;
    private EditText etResponse;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnRequest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRequest);
        etResponse = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRespose);

         //check isConnected()...code is on github
        btnRequest.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        new HttpHandler() {
            @Override
            public HttpUriRequest getHttpRequestMethod() {

                return new HttpGet("http://hmkcode.com/examples/index.php");

                // return new HttpPost(url)
            }
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String result) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                etResponse.setText(result);
            }

        }.execute();
    }
    // public boolean isConnected(){}
  }
```

reference 
http://hmkcode.com/android-cleaner-http-asynctask/

https://github.com/hmkcode/Android/tree/master/android-clean-http-async-task

Comment: I'll try this but I found the answer in previous answer. thanks for help